# How can I plot a line between last highest high and last lowest low?

Tags: pine-script

### can please someone enlighten me with the following uncertain?

I want to plot a line between the last highest high and the last lowest low, I used valuewhen to get the value for that, but for a reason that I don't know, it gives me the previous value, that means the line would be always late with a candle.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

upper = highest(high, 20)
lower = lowest(low, 20)

plot(upper)
plot(lower)

val_u = valuewhen(upper > upper[1], upper, 0)
val_l = valuewhen(lower < lower[1], lower, 0)

plot(val_u, color = color.red)
plot(val_l, color = color.red)
barss_u = barssince(upper > upper[1])
barss_l = barssince(lower < lower[1])

l = line.new(bar_index[barss_u], val_u, bar_index[barss_l], val_l, width = 1, color = color.orange, style=line.style_dashed)
line.delete(l[1])
```

This is how it looks, red line is the valuewhen, blue line is the high/low level, orange line should be the connection line between last lower low and last higher high, but for a reason that I don't know, the valuewhen does not update in real time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `valuewhen` works, it does not take the current bar into account. Try `highestbars` and `lowestbars` instead:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

barss_u = highestbars(20) * -1
barss_l = lowestbars(20) * -1

val_u = high[barss_u]
val_l = low[barss_l]

l = line.new(bar_index[barss_u], val_u, bar_index[barss_l], val_l, width = 1, color = color.orange, style=line.style_dashed)
line.delete(l[1])
```

**UPDATE**

You can fix the lag of `valuewhen` with the following code:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

upper = highest(high, 20)
lower = lowest(low, 20)

plot(upper)
plot(lower)

x_val_u = valuewhen(upper > upper[1], upper, 0)
x_val_l = valuewhen(lower < lower[1], lower, 0)

val_u = high >= upper ? high : x_val_u
val_l = low <= lower ? low : x_val_l

plot(val_u, color = color.red)
plot(val_l, color = color.red)
barss_u = barssince(upper > upper[1])
barss_l = barssince(lower < lower[1])

l = line.new(bar_index[barss_u], val_u, bar_index[barss_l], val_l, width = 1, color = color.orange, style=line.style_dashed)
line.delete(l[1])
```

The green line shows how this new version works:

[image: BTCUDS, 60]

Comment: This is working for that purpose, but I still need to get those values from `highestbars` and `lowestbars`, and the only method I know to do this is to use `valuewhen`, which will brings me back to the main problem

Comment: `high[barss_u]` and `low[barss_l]` give you the actual prices, is this what you need?

Comment: My main goal is to take the last time where was a lower low and last time where was a higher high (and not LL and HH from last x candles) and connect them with a line, just like in my script, but without that `valuewhen` one candle lag.

Comment: @edward I've updated the answer, take a look, please.